# Running shell commands from c++ code

Tags: c++, terminal

Is there a function with which I can run commands from the terminal through my c++ code.

For example, if in the code I have the name of the user i can create a string that will greet the user and then run the terminal command say "Helo user" so that the person would hear that.

Hope I could explain myself, thanks in advance.

Comment: What about?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Comment: Thank you my man, I appreciate it!